# Installing Ubuntu Server 18.04 on Intel board S500VSA

Tags: networking, drivers, server

I am relatively a newbie level user on Ubuntu. I have a few laptops that run Ubuntu desktop and I was able to get them going (with some forum searching help).
However, this time all my searches did not produce any results. So, I hope you guys can help me resolve some issues with the network.

I understand that Ubuntu Server does not have drivers for onboard Ethernet controllers. So I found an available WiFi adapter that I used. During the server installation, the installer did not see any network. I also did not create any bond. I assumed that after installation I would be able to use my WiFi adapter to connect to the network and install the Ethernet drivers.

However, after installation I get the following output for `lshw -C network` command:

`*-network:0 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 80003ES2LAN Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b8820000-b883ffff memory:b8400000-b87fffff ioport:3020(size=32)   *-network:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 80003ES2LAN Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b8800000-b881ffff memory:b8000000-b83fffff ioport:3000(size=32)   *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlx000f60055331
       serial: 00:0f:60:05:53:31
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.15.0-55-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11`

The output from `ip address` command:

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlx000f60055331: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0f:60:05:53:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

Any recommendations on how can I get the WiFi adapter going?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the output of 'ip address'? If you see a network device, your system did load the card driver but is not configured through netplan.

Comment: @ThomasAichinger I apologize for the delayed reply. I missed the notification email. Added the output of the `ip address` command to the question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can see that the driver was loaded and your wifi card wlx000f60055331 is working but has no IP address. To get or set an IP address you first have to connect to your wifi with SSID and passphrase.

Comment: @ThomasAichinger What command would I use to connect to WiFi network? `sudo iw dev wlx000f60055331 scan` command provides 'network is down' output. Network Manager is not installed in Server installation.